# WCF Message headers server and client

Tags: wcf, header, message

I want my WCF client to attach some information with every call to wcf server, and that information can be retireved on server side.

And the server can also attach some information to every response and that information can be retirved by client.

I want to implement this for every end point and i dont want to add code for every wcf call. I want something global.

Thanks in advance,

Mrinal Jaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like to need to implement a WCF "message inspector". Try this MSDN magazine article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163302.aspx.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. It was able to resolve my issue. But it slows my call in case of HTTP end points. It works for Net Tcp end points pretty well but in case of HTTP end points the call is taking too much of time. Any suggestions :)